# Sbt RootProject or ProjectRef doesn't download github project content

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I'm trying to refer to a project in github from my current project as source dependency. Have the following settings in build.sbt

```
lazy val `some-api` = (project in file("."))
.enablePlugins(PlayJava)
.dependsOn(common)
.settings(...)

lazy val common =
ProjectRef(uri("git://git@github.com:XXX/XXX.git#initial-version"), "XXX")
```

Running sbt compile or package creates a folder with the project name in `.sbt/1.0/staging/(someid)` but it doesn't download the project content. I can only see a `target` folder inside it with scala-2.12 and streams folders. Am i missing something here?

Note that I've tried RootProject setting as well.

```
lazy val common =
RootProject(uri("git://git@github.com:XXX/XXX.git#initial-version"))
```

Also, how do I setup to update the external project dependency during a clean compile or package? It doesn't look like the external project content is refreshed unless I delete the folder under staging.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like with `git://git@github.com`, sbt adds `--depth 1` when cloning. Switching to `http://github.com/` solved it. Raised it with lightbend to get better idea around this. Hope it helps :)